# difference between "education" "educational " "educated"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

education noun

educated adj

educational adj

what is difference between "highly educated" and "highly educational" and difference between  "education level" educational level

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

**education** means the study we do or the knowledge we get from schools and colleges etc.
**educated** means someone who has received the knowledge (education).
**educational** means something that provides that knowledge (education).

**"highly educated"** means someone who has studied up to a high level.
**"highly educational"** means something that provides a high level / a lot of of knowledge.